Movie about aliens attacking the earth with an invisible net
Aliens attacking the earth by creating some sort of invisible net that absorbs humans inside. 
The Military tries to bombard and put missiles to stop the net..but it also just goes inside without any explosion. 
There is one guy(the scientist or something) who puts bomb on himself and voluntarily goes inside the net to explode it, but nothing....in between the movie, they show glimpses of people who are sucked inside the net screaming...they seem to be tied up....i think aliens also poisoned the water.
Aired on tv in the 90s.

I think you're describing the Invasion: Earth miniseries from 1998.  I don't remember an invisible net, but rather

An amorphous mountain of alien tentacles and design appears on the
  outskirts of Kirkhaven, and it begins expanding, swallowing up and
  absorbing all the surrounding organic matter and transporting it back
  to the nDs' home.

There are scenes of captured humans in agony inside the net.  The aliens kidnap them

in order to use them as living batteries.

Additionally,

The previously escaped NATO officer is running amok in the
  countryside. He drives to a reservoir some miles away, cuts his
  brachial artery and throws himself into the dam, where he bleeds to
  death.

This was to infect whoever drank the water, not to poison them. 

yeahh u r right!!! i think this is the one!! thanx a lot
